# I can't think how to move the column

Tags: c

So i am making a game for my final work, its like "the sample game".
I already made almost all the code but i can't find a solution for my last function, the fuction must see if the column is empty (full of zeros) and if so, send it to the right of all the other columns. here is my code (all the function must start with the arguments they have, its a part of the work) the fuction i am having problems is called "colunas":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>//para poder usar char's e strings
#include <stdbool.h>//para poder usar o while true
#include <time.h>//para poder usar seeds diferentes na funçao srand

int marcar(int sz, int tabuleiro[sz][sz], int x, int y)//vai contar o numero de quadrados do grupo
{
  int num=0;
  for (x = 0; x < sz; x++)
  {
    for (y = 0; y < sz; y++)
    {
      if(tabuleiro[x][y] == 9)//os ciclos vao percorrer o tabuleiro e vao verificar os 0s
      {
        num=num+1;//num vai contar o numero de 0s
      }
    }
  }
  return num;//retornar o numero de 0s
}

//pontuacao
int pontuacao(int num_quadrados)
{
  int pontos;
  pontos=(num_quadrados*(num_quadrados + 1))/2;
  return pontos;
}


//gravidade
/*
void gravidade(int sz, int tabuleiro[sz][sz])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < sz+1; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++)
    {
      if (tabuleiro[i][j] == 9)
      {
        tabuleiro[i][j] = tabuleiro[i-1][j];
        tabuleiro[i-1][j] = 9;
      }
    }
  }
}
*/

void gravidade(int sz, int tabuleiro[sz][sz])
{
  int c = 0;
  while(c < sz)//utilizamos esta variavel apra percorrer o ciclo todas as vezes necessarias para fazer todos os 9s subir
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < sz-1; i++)//percorre as linhas
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++)//percorre as colunas
      {
        if (tabuleiro[i][j] == 9 && i < sz-1)
        {
          tabuleiro[i][j] = tabuleiro[i+1][j];//muda o valor do zero para o valor acima 
          tabuleiro[i+1][j] = 9;//muda o valor que esta acima do valor copiado, para 0
        }
      }
    }
  c++;
  }
}


//jogada
int jogada(int sz, int tabuleiro[sz][sz], int x, int y)
{
  if((x>=0 && x<sz) && (y>=0  && y<sz))//definimos o limite do x e do y
  {
    int temp = tabuleiro[x][y];
    tabuleiro[x][y] = 9;  //alterar o valor de tabuleiro para impedir as chamadas infinitas da recursividade
    if(tabuleiro[x+1][y] == temp)//para verificar a direita
    {
      jogada(sz, tabuleiro, x+1, y);//chamar a função recursivamente
    }
    if (tabuleiro[x-1][y] == temp)//para verificar a esquerda
    {
      jogada(sz, tabuleiro, x-1, y);
    }
    if (tabuleiro[x][y+1] == temp)//para verificar em cima
    {
      jogada(sz, tabuleiro, x, y+1);
    } if(tabuleiro[x][y-1] == temp)//para verificar em baixo
    {
      jogada(sz, tabuleiro, x, y-1);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

void troca(int sz, int tabuleiro[sz][sz])//mudar o zero para o proximo ciclo ele nao contar com os zeros da jogada anterior
{
  for (int x = 0; x < sz; x++)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y < sz; y++)
    {
      if(tabuleiro[x][y] == 9)//os ciclos vao percorrer o tabuleiro e vao verificar os 0s
      {
        tabuleiro[x][y] = 0;//vao passar os 9 todos a 0
      }
    }
  }
}

//mover as colunas vazias
int coluna(int sz, int tabuleiro[sz][sz])
{
  //this is the function i cant solve
}

//Mostra o tabuleiro
void mostrar(int sz, int tabuleiro[sz][sz])
{
  for (int i = sz-1; i >= 0; i--)//for para o numero de linhas, usamos o sz-1 pois o indice do array começa no 0 e i>=0 para poder chegar ao indice 0
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++) //for para o numero de colunas
    {
      printf("%d", tabuleiro[i][j]); //print das linhas
    }
    printf("\n");//baixar a linha quando chega a coluna n-1
  }
}

//main
int main()
{
  //definição do tabuleiro
  int sz;//size do tabuleiro
  printf("Escolha o valor de n (da matriz n*n):\n");
  scanf("%d", &sz);//scan do size
  printf("\n");
  int tabuleiro[sz][sz];//o size é igual para as colunas como para as linhas pois a matriz é n*n
  srand(time(NULL));//função utilizada para alterar a seed do rand (gerador de valores aleatórios)
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)//for para o numero de linhas, usamos o sz-1 pois o indice do array começa no 0 e i>=0 para poder chegar ao indice 0
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++)//for para o numero de colunas
    {
      tabuleiro[i][j] = rand() %4 + 1;//gerar a matriz com valores aleatórios
    }
  } 

  int jx, jy, mx, my, pontos;
  pontos=0;

  while(true)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++)
      {
          mostrar(sz, tabuleiro);
          printf("\n");

          printf("(0,0) e o canto inferior esquerdo\n");
          printf("Escolha o x (lembrando que x = x+1 linhas exemplo x(1) = linha 2):\n");//acontece devido ao índice começar no 0 e não no 1
          scanf("%d", &jx);
          printf("\n");

          printf("Escolha o y (lembrando que y = y+1 colunas exemplo y(1) = coluna 2):\n");//acontece devido ao índice começar no 0 e não no 1
          scanf("%d", &jy);

          if(tabuleiro[jx][jy] != 0) //utilizamos este if para condicionar a posicao pois se escolher 0 ele contava os pontos de todos os zeros juntos
          {
            jogada(sz, tabuleiro, jx, jy);
            printf("\n");

            gravidade(sz, tabuleiro);//assim sempre que uma jogada é executada ele faz a funçao gravidade

            int p = marcar(sz, tabuleiro, mx, my);
            pontuacao(p);

            pontos=pontos+pontuacao(p);

            printf("Pontos:\n");
            printf("%d\n", pontos);
            printf("\n");

            troca(sz, tabuleiro);
          }
          else
          {
            printf("\n");
            printf("Nao e possivel escolher uma posicao onde o valor de tabuleiro[x][y] seja 0\n");
            printf("\n");
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i am hoping for help,
thank you for the time spent.

Comment: What have you tried so far to implement "coluna"? One simple and naive solution is to move all non-zero columns to the left.

Comment: hmmm, yes that should work! how could i do that?? because i only want to move the column when it becomes full of zeros not when it has one or more.

Comment: I've tried to use the position given by the player to see if that column is full of zeros or not, but that would just move one column, and itwon't work...

Comment: Well, check if the column is full of zeros, and if it is you just need to copy the contents of the immediately right column to it. This is the basic idea, but you may need to consider cases in which two or more subsequently columns are zero.

Comment: yes that's the problem... how would i fix that problme of 2 or more columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this (comments explain the code):

```
void coluna(int size, int board[size][size]){
    int not_zeros[size]; // Use to save the index of columns that contain at 
                         // least one number different than zero.
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        not_zeros[i] = -1; //initialize the array.

    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
        int foundNotZero = 0;
        for (j=0; j<size; j++){
            if(board[j][i] != 0){ //line j, column i.
                foundNotZero = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (foundNotZero == 1){ //at least one element of the column i is not zero.
            not_zeros[i] = i;
        }
    }
    int start = 0;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        if (not_zeros[i] >= 0){ //copy column i to column start.
            for(j = 0; j<size; j++){
                board[j][start] = board[j][not_zeros[i]];
            }
            start++; //increment start.
        }
    }
    for(i=start; i<size; i++){
        for(j=0; j<size; j++){
            board[j][i] = 0; //fill the remaining columns with zeros.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Miketue accept the answer if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
int coluna(int sz, int tabuleiro[sz][sz])
{
    int i, j, k, m;
    i= 0;
    m= sz;
    while (i<m) {
        int allzeroes= 1;
        for (j=0; j<sz; j++) {
            if (tabuleiro[i][j]!=0) {
                allzeroes= 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (allzeroes) {    // col i is all zeroes
            // move all remaining cols down 1 col
            for (j=i; j<m-1; j++)
                for (k=0; k<sz; k++)
                    tabuleiro[j][k]= tabuleiro[j+1][k];

            // zero last column
            for (k=0; k<sz; k++)
                tabuleiro[m-1][j]= 0;

            // new last col that is not zero
            m--;
        }
        else i++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes but the column should move to the left not down, you are cheking it for the rows not the colums

Comment: Thank you for trying to help btw!